# How to return generic type T when instantiating a subclass of T

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I want to get a Parametrized class which is able to return an object of type T AND children of T

This is the code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

class A {};

class B extends A {};

public class testGenerics<T extends A> {

  T a;

  T getA() {
    return getA(B.class); // Compilation problem:
    //The method getA(Class<T>) in the type testGenerics<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<B>)
  }

  T getA(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
      return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
  }

}
```

This is how I think:

I am declaring generic type T, that extends A. Therefore, I can create from Class clazz an instance of type T extending A.

However, when I decide to get A from B.class (Which extends A):

```
getA(B.class)
```

I get following error:

> The method getA(Class< T >) in the type testGenerics< T > is not applicable for the arguments (Class< B >)

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: @Thomas This does not fix the reported compilation problem.

Comment: Right, saw that. The problem is something different: `T` is bound to the instance of `testGenerics` (should be `TestGenerics` btw.) and thus could be something other than `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the class definition `class testGenerics<T extends A>`.

That means that `T` is defined when creating an instance of that class and could be bound to any subclass of `A` - which might not be `B` but `C` etc. Thus passing  `B.class` isn't guaranteed to match.

To fix that put the defintion of `T` at the method level:

```
<T extends A> A getA(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
  return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
}

//No generics needed here, since the method above returns A anyways.
//If it'd return T you'd have to change the return type here to B since getA(B.class) binds T to be B now
A getA() throws Exception {
  return getA(B.class); 
}
```

Since the method level `T` hides the definition at the class level you need to do something about that: either use a different name (e.g. `S`) or remove the definition at the class level (it doesn't make much sense there anyways).

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because `B` is not `T`. Yes, `B` also extends `T`, but it is not `T`. Imagine you have also a class `C extends A` and create an instance of `testGenerics<C>`. Your `getA()` method would instantiate `B` but should return `C`. The following, however, works fine with a few tweaks:

```
testGenerics<B> tg = new testGenerics<B>();
B b = tg.getA(B.class);
```

How to fix this depends on what you actually want to do. This, for instance allows you to instantiate any subclass of `A`:

```
  public <S extends A> S getA(Class<S> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
      return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
  }
```

However you can't really use `T` here (like `<S extends T>`). Since `T` is a parameter type, you have no guarantees on whether `B` is or extends `T`.